# LLDB throwing auto import error in Swift Xcode project

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

I'm trying to use the debugger in Xcode to poke around in one of my methods.  The app is pretty bare bones, just one example class at this point.  When I set a breakpoint and run, the LLDB debugger pane opens in Xcode as expected.  However, if I try to execute a print command to poke around in my method, I get the following error:

```
Error in auto-import:
Failed to load linked library Cocoa of module ExampleAppTests - errors:
Looking for "@rpath/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa", error: not a string object
Looking for "/Users/Elliot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExampleApp-aqpflidffjffyzdxfjdfbjijvsxq/Build/Products/Debug/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
Looking for "/BinaryCache/arclite/arclite-49.1~7/Symbols/BuiltProducts/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
Looking for "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
Looking for "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
Looking for "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
Looking for "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Cocoa.framework/Cocoa"
,    error: not a string object
```

I get the same error if I enter the repl and execute a command.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with a similar app.

Comment: I'm seeing the same, with Crashlytics. It is making debugging impossible. Did anyone find a resolution?

Comment: @theLastNightTrain I'm having the same issue with Crashlytics, I contacted them about it and am still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here! We reached out to Apple on the behavior that everyone is seeing and they confirmed it's a bug in LLDB around Swift. We don't have an firm timeline yet as to when it will be fixed, but the bug report that it's being tracked in is 18256812.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm still having this issue.

Comment: I did some research. I've created new project and start making changes one by one. Here are the results: Add and init cocoapods - OK. Add and setup Fabric + Crashlytics - OK. Add and setup TwitterKit (from Fabric) - Failed. By fail I mean - debugging in console is impossible.

Comment: I've found temporary solution here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/xcode-7-debugger/50792/21 One thing I don't get is why Fabric didn't fix it yet.

Comment: Twitter pods from fabric were updated and starting version 1.12.0 they don't break the debugger. Yay!